# Where can I find specific Apple firmware like early 2011 SMC 1.69f3

Tags: macbook-pro, firmware

I would like to load a specific firmware from https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201518

My research shows the MacBook Pro early 2011 SMC 1.69f3 seems to be stable. I use links on apple website shows "page not found" when clicked on the update 1.5. Can someone please help me provide the SMC 1.69f3.

Are there places to download this software?

Comment: …when you clicked on **what** update? SMC 1.69f3 ***is*** v 1.5

Comment: this link https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201518..

Comment: and when clicked on 1.69f3.. it goes to https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1474?locale=en_IN.. and the error The page you're looking for can't be found.

Comment: the apples website has removed this firmware 1.69f3 from their website.

Comment: What OS are you on? Firmware updates are usually included in OS updates & don't need to be done separately. Have you also checked what your current firmware version is? Your question is lacking in detail.

Comment: am on sierra. the macbook hangs and doesnt come up again until i reset nvram and smc. all sorts of problems..

Comment: i need the specific version of 1.69f3 and i use rEFit to flash the smc through efi mode

Comment: Have you tried downloading the necessary macOS/OS X updates and extracting the firmwares from them to find the right one?

Comment: there is no place on internet where i can download smc 1.69f3.. not even from apple website.

Answer (score 1):

For most people, I recommend always going forward, never backward. I’m sure someone has squirreled away copies, but I don’t have any source I trust to get old firmware.

There are ways to flash firmware without Apple’s loader process - [How to downgrade SMC firmware](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/257823/how-to-downgrade-smc-firmware)

---

As you notice, since the updates now happen when you install macOS updates and
upgrades the older Apple page is archived and not maintained or migrated to the new hosting support sites.
In the case you seek to down level, I've not ever seen that work. I’m not saying you couldn’t be the first case to achieve that, but the issues tend to be failing hardware and not that the newer firmware has some bug Apple doesn’t then fix with even newer patch.

I’m not saying you’re wrong, just my experience is this hasn’t helped in the past. I hope you prove me wrong in this case and can report success getting the code and that it helps as you expect. Documenting it publicly and the checksum of known good firmware will be a service to everyone.

Keeping “obsolete” or “vintage” gear in full operation makes me very happy and is a worthy goal.

Comment: my macbook early 2011 has issues.. freezes and goes blank during boots.. and i  realised i was not able to update boot rom beyond 87.0.0.0 and i updated the smc to 1.69f4 which makes the fans speed go very slow.. and any other version of smc firmware from the apples website makes just one fan spin... am stuck with 1.69f4.. my earlier 1.69f3 was stable and had no fan speed issues...

Comment: can i get anyone who wud have downloaded this smc 1.69f3 version.. now apple has scrapped that version and i need that version to flash back my macbook to that stable version

Comment: The flash back  is going to be an issue. I’ve never seen Apple installers allow that even if someone squirreled away the upgrade package. How are you going to manage the downgrade? @RaviKumar

Comment: i have used/use rEFit software to boot from USB after belssing the usb and then i do a SmcFlasher.efi -reset 1" and then "SmcFlasher.efi -force -LoadApp 2011MBP15.smc

Comment: all i need is 1.69f3 version of SMC which is 1.5 update for macbook pro early 2011 15 inches

Comment: Perfect. I’m not saying you’re wrong, just my experience is this hasn’t helped in the past. If you add all this excellent detail to your post perhaps someone will see it. Buried in the comments most will never see your actual plan and technical research. Please I hope you prove me wrong and can report success getting the code and that it helps as you expect. @RaviKumar keeping “obsolete” or “vintage” gear in full operation makes me very happy.

Comment: with SMC i can install any version( up / down) without any issues.. i just need someone to help me with giving me the 1.69f3 to put it back.. i have installed lower versions and it has issues with fan speed/throttle issues.. i realised 1.69f3 works fine.. Yes  i am unable to run the efi firmware(boot rom) by downloading the dmg file from the apple site and running it.. says its not valid for my system.. With SMC i can install anything..

Comment: Infact if i get locked i get into the emergency mode by removing the battery.. keeping the power button pressed and connecting the adapter and keeping the power button held for 5 secs and releasing.. that boots the laptop with fan speed maxed and gets into the OS. i use that method to reflash the SMC.. if i get the 1.69f3 i am saved.. please help me..

Comment: i have two macbook pros.. one the 15 inch early..2011... and i have the gem macbook pro  mid 2012 15 inch.. thats super stable and fantastic..

Comment: 2011 has issues with GPU and a lot more issues.. very very unstable and a bad hardware.

Comment: The chances it’s SMC that will restore stability is quite slim indeed as you point out.

Comment: i will take the risk. can someone help me get that smc version.